# expo-updates: You cannot use the Updates module in development mode in a production app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, eas, expo-updates

I'm trying to update expo sdk from 46 to 49 and when I update all the packages I faced a problem related to `expo-updates` package

in the application I'm using RTL with a default language `ar` so I need to reload application if RTL is false for the first time or when user change the language.

the problem is when running the application on `Expo Go` for the first time this error appears

```
WARN  [Error: You cannot use the Updates module in development mode in a production app. To test manual updates, publish your project using `expo publish` and open the published version in this development client.]
```

and when I try to generate a standalone app with the `eas` command the application crushes or gets stuck in the splash screen.

here's the the part were i reload the application

```
const loadI18n = async () => {
      const lang: string | null = await localStorage.getValue("lang");
      const selectedLanguage: LanguageModel = env.languages.find((x: LanguageModel) => x.lang === ((lang !== null) ? lang : env.defaultLanguage));

      if (lang === null) {
        localStorage.save("lang", env.defaultLanguage);
      } else {
        console.log("a language is already selected, The language: ", lang)
      }
      i18n.init()
        .then(async () => {
          console.log("==============> I18nManager.isRTL: ", I18nManager.isRTL)
          const RNDir = selectedLanguage.layout;
          console.log("isRTL: ", RNDir);
          console.log("current language is :", i18next.language, "i18n.dir: ", i18n.dir);
          if ((i18n.dir !== RNDir) || (!I18nManager.isRTL && selectedLanguage.layout === 'RTL')) {
            console.log("isRTL: ", RNDir);
            console.log("current language is :", i18next.language, "i18n.dir: ", i18n.dir);
            const isLocaleRTL = selectedLanguage.layout === 'RTL';
            I18nManager.forceRTL(isLocaleRTL);
            I18nManager.allowRTL(isLocaleRTL);
            console.log("isLocaleRTL: ", selectedLanguage.layout === 'RTL');
            await Updates.reloadAsync();
          }
          setIsI18nInitialized(true);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => console.warn(error));
    }
```

and here's the eas file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.5.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "qaMA": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "releaseChannel": "qa",
      "env": {
        "APP_COUNTRY": "MA"
      }
    },
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

command I built with `eas build -p android --profile qaMA`

Answer (score 0):

Same situation.
i was ugraded expo SDK 44 to 49.
with same language library.

Comment: yeah, I ended up downgrading to SDK 46 and this works again

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is in the `await Updates.reloadAsync();` command. This is intended for the Expo Updates mechanic but used to be applied creatively as a means to reset the app in other situations. Sadly, the way the Updates feature works has changed and this command can no longer be used in a DEV build.

> This method cannot be used in development mode, and the returned promise will be rejected if you try to do so.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/#updatesreloadasync